# Why does `this` create a global variable instead of using the variable from the call site?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm reading the *You Don't Know JS* books and am on *this and Object Prototypes*.

I get that to know what `this` refers to I need to look at the call-site. And the call site is what `this` will refer to. What I don't get is why this code isn't working as I think it should (I only wrote it to understand `this`, not for any working problem or anything).

```
function foo() {
  console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty('a')); // 1
  console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('a')); // 2
  console.log(this.a); // 3
  this.a++;
  console.log(window.hasOwnProperty('a')); // 4

}
function bar(){
  foo.a = 42;
  foo();
}
bar();
```

1. If you look at the first line in `bar` which creates an `a` property for `foo` and assigns it the value 42. If I comment this line out, then running `console.log(foo.hasOwnProperty('a'));` gives me false. And if I have it run, then it returns true. But if this is the case, then calling `bar` is indeed creating an `a` property for foo, right? This leads to question 3.
2. I get that at this point `window.a` does not exist.
3. Why does this return `undefined`? `this` should resolve to `foo.a`, right? Because the context of `this` would be in `bar`, correct? `Bar` is the call-site. However, this remains `undefined` regardless of whether `foo.a = 42` is commented out or not.
4. Why does this return `true` now, after running `this.a++`? How and why is a global variable being created?

Comment: The `this` keyword inside function refers to the object the function belongs to, or the window object if the function belongs to no object. So `this` and `foo` are two different objects.

Comment: `foo()` is a free function (a function that do not belongs to an object) then *this*  is undefined.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - simply incorrect - "this" refers to the window object.

Comment: @fraser and what if your are in a freestanding runtime environment? ECMAScript doesn't require to have a `window` object.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - But in this case there clearly is a window object, and it is part of the point of discussion. So saying "this is undefined" is simply incorrect in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In foo `this` refers to the parent object - i.e. window.

so `this.a` and `window.a` are referring to the same thing.

> Because the context of this would be in bar, correct?

Incorrect. For bar to be "this" in foo you would need to `apply` or `call` or `bind` foo passing your desired "this" as context. i.e.

```
foo.call({});

or 

foo.bind({});
```

Would make "this" and empty object within `foo`.

> Why does this return true now, after running this.a++? How and why is
>   a global variable being created?

For the same reason - when you do this.a++ you are creating and incrementing a global variable `a` by one.

Comment: But why is the context **not** `bar` is what I don't get! The book says I'm to look at the call site - "The call-site we care about is in the invocation before the currently
executing function." 

Would this make the call site `bar`? And therefore the context would be the body of the `bar` function, no?

Comment: no - inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called. Because in your example the value of "this" is not set by the call, this will default to the global object - i.e. window - see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I'd also point out doing `func()`  and  `new func()` have different meanings.  As the OP has not used `new`, there is no `this` in the classic sense.

Comment: @keith - Not sure what you mean by classic sense - this is clearly defined as the global object - in every sense I can think of in the given context.

Comment: Classic sense as in `new func()` as that's were 99% of `this` context gets bound.  Ps.  I'm not correcting you with anything you said, but thought worth pointing this out too, as you mentioned `apply` `bind` and `call`  but just missed out `new func()`.  So `this` would be global as there has been no binding whatsoever.

Comment: @Keith - Ah I get what you mean now yes...I just wasn't sure what you meant by "classic" sense...obviously strict mode and arrow functions also have nuances this too, but yes - new is a "classic" example of how this gets bound.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this is just an easy way of thinking about `this`. In complicated cases (such as when using `.bind()` or OOP), the following might not be accurate.

`this`, by default sorta refers to the object that contains the function being called. For example, if I did

```
var obj = {
    fxn: function() {
        console.log(this.bar);
    },
    bar: 3
}
obj.fxn(); // (1)
var fxn = obj.fxn();
fxn(); // (2)
```

`(1)` Will print "3" to the console; Because you are, in a way, calling `fxn` "through" `obj`, `this` will point to `obj`. In other words, because you are calling the copy of `fxn` that is stored inside of `obj`, `this` will point to `obj`.

`(2)` Will (assuming `bar` has not been defined elsewhere) print undefined. That is because `fxn` isn't being called "through" anything. As a result, it pretends that `fxn` is being called through `window`.

Although in your example, `foo` is being called *in* `bar`, `bar` does not call a version of `foo` being... well, stored inside itself. `bar` does not call `foo`... "through" `foo`.

Admittedly, that's pretty confusing. Maybe this will clear up some confusion: If you change `bar` to this:

```
function bar(){
    foo.a = 42;
    foo.foo = foo;
    foo.foo();
}
```

it will print `42` instead of undefined. The important part is that the object that `foo` is being called through will be `this`. For instance,

```
function bar(){
    var baz = {};
    baz.a = 42;
    baz.foo = foo;
    baz.foo();
}
```

Will also print 42.

Comment: In nearly every case, the value of "this" is determined by *how* a function is called - not what its parent is. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

Comment: @Fraser this is also what's confusing me - isn't it a _where_ question, instead of a _how_ question? If I'm looking at _where_ the function was called, and I'm looking at the call-site, I'm looking at the where, not the how, right?

Comment: @firefiber Wrong - it is *how* that determines the value of "this" in the function not where. That said obviously you do have to look at the callsite to see *how* it is being called.

Comment: @Fraser I've updated my answer to hopefully articulate it better. Is this what you mean?